# Can I build a jsonArray from jsonObject in android

Tags: android

I have a jsonObject which I wanna pass to a webservice the jsonObject is going to dynamic 
sample -

```
{"data1":"data1data","data2":"data2data"}
```

So how can I convert it to JSONArray and send it
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject("{"data1":"data1data","data2":"data2data"}");
JSONArray array = new JSONArray();
array.put(json);
```

To put that array in a HTTP call, post for example:

```
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPut put = new HttpPut(uri); 
put.setEntity(new StringEntity(array.toString()));
put.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");
httpResponse = client.execute(put);
```

Comment: Jon that worked can you guide how can i pass to a webservice by coz this turns errors **params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("array", array));**

Comment: If the answer is correct mark it as answer please. First, if you want to pass a parameter named array use new BasicNameValuePair("array", array.toString()). But probably you just want to pass the array as JSON. I will edit my answer with an example.